# MS SQL Server counting nulls by column in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have been given a task to find how many nulls there are for each column in a given table. The table has many columns (50-80, depending on the individual table). I would like the result pivoted so the column names are records, like this:

| column_name | null_count |
| --- | --- |
| columnA | 253 |
| columnB | 25 |
| columnC | 0 |
| columnD | 456 |
| ... | ... |

Currently, I do

```
SELECT 'columnA' as column_name, sum(case when columnA IS NULL then 1 else 0 end) null_count from [table] UNION
SELECT 'columnB', sum(case when columnB IS NULL then 1 else 0 end) from [table] UNION
...
```

for all the rows. This is kind of tedious and I would like to know if there is a more flexible way to do this in MS Sql Server management studio. Maybe something that can step through each record in [database].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.

Comment: Aside: Using [`union all`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) avoids the overhead of eliminating duplicate rows, a service provided by `union`. When you know there can't be duplicates it behooves you to you to use `union all` to avoid the performance hit.

Comment: Did you have a chance to try the proposed solution below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

It is using SQL Server's XML and XQuery magic.
No need for dynamic SQL.

We are leveraging a fact that `FOR XML ...` clause omits columns with NULL values.

**SQL**

```
USE tempdb;
GO

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.tbl;

-- DDL and sample data population, start
CREATE TABLE dbo.tbl (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, columnA INT, columnB VARCHAR(5), columnC INT);
INSERT dbo.tbl (columnA, columnB, columnC) VALUES
(1, NULL, NULL),
(2, 'city', NULL),
(NULL, 'cat', NULL),
(100, NULL, NULL);
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @total_row_counter BIGINT = (SELECT COUNT_BIG(*) FROM dbo.tbl);

;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT column_name = c.value('local-name(.)', 'sysname')
    FROM dbo.tbl AS p
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT * 
                    FROM dbo.tbl AS c 
                    WHERE c.ID = p.ID
                    FOR XML PATH('root'), TYPE) AS t1(x)
        CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/root/*') AS t2(c)
)
SELECT sch.column_name, null_counter = @total_row_counter - COUNT_BIG(rs.column_name)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS sch
    LEFT OUTER JOIN rs ON sch.COLUMN_NAME = rs.column_name
WHERE TABLE_CATALOG = 'TEMPDB'
   AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
   AND TABLE_NAME = 'tbl'
GROUP BY sch.column_name
ORDER BY sch.column_name;
```

**SQL #2**

It covers table column names with spaces. A minor `FOR XML ...` clause change automatically converts spaces into `_x0020_` in the XML element names.

```
<root>
  <ID>3</ID>
  <column_x0020_B>cat</column_x0020_B>
</root>
```

The rest is identical.

```
USE tempdb;
GO

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.tbl;

-- DDL and sample data population, start
CREATE TABLE dbo.tbl (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, columnA INT, [column B] VARCHAR(5), columnC INT);
INSERT dbo.tbl (columnA, [column B], columnC) VALUES
(1, NULL, NULL),
(2, 'city', NULL),
(NULL, 'cat', NULL),
(100, NULL, NULL);
-- DDL and sample data population, end
        
DECLARE @total_row_counter BIGINT = (SELECT COUNT_BIG(*) FROM dbo.tbl);

;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT column_name = REPLACE(c.value('local-name(.)', 'sysname'), '_x0020_', SPACE(1))
    FROM dbo.tbl AS p
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT * 
                    FROM dbo.tbl AS [root]
                    WHERE [root].ID = p.ID
                    FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS, TYPE) AS t1(x)
        CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/root/*') AS t2(c)
)
SELECT sch.column_name, null_counter = @total_row_counter - COUNT_BIG(rs.column_name)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS sch
    LEFT OUTER JOIN rs ON sch.COLUMN_NAME = rs.column_name
WHERE TABLE_CATALOG = 'TEMPDB'
   AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
   AND TABLE_NAME = 'tbl'
GROUP BY sch.column_name
ORDER BY sch.column_name;
```

**Output**

```
+-------------+--------------+
| column_name | null_counter |
+-------------+--------------+
| columnA     |            1 |
| columnB     |            2 |
| columnC     |            4 |
| ID          |            0 |
+-------------+--------------+
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the empty statement between the `declare` and the CTE? Using two statement terminators seems like overkill.

Comment: It is just a personal habit to prevent CTE from failing. It is not mandatory.

Comment: Hello, and thank you for the solution. Through attempting to implement this, I discovered one of our field names has a whitespace trailing it, creating an invalid identifier for Xquery. I have raised a ticket with our developer and will try again after it's resolved.

Comment: Please check the **SQL #2**. It supports spaces in the column names.